# Woocommerce Change Recent Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change my recent products to an overview about the author of the product in my single product page.

I don't know where to find the code to the recent products. I looked for it in the single-product.php but I didn't find it.

If it helps: I use `WooCommerce` Version 2.6.9 and `Wordpress` Version 4.7.

[image: Products]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will find it there: **WP-admin > Appearance > widgets > right sidebar**

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit **sidebar.php** in **theme options** folder or in **woocommerce templates** folder